# addEventListener firing on page load

Tags: jquery, iframe, addeventlistener

I am trying to have a iframe modal pop-up on the parent of an iframe after I click a link in the iframe.  This works but the addEventListener function on the parent page fires on page load rather than waiting on the click from the child iframe.  I've searched over this site and cannot find the answer I'm looking for.  Here is the code from the parent:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#closer").click(function () {
        $("body").css('overflow','auto');
        $(".overlay").hide("fast");
    });

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        $("body").css('overflow','hidden');
        $(".overlay").show("fast");
        console.log("Hello from " + event.data);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the code from the child iframe:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $(".standard").click(do_stuff);

    function do_stuff(){
        parent.postMessage("child frame", "*");
    }
});
</script>
```

I added the console log to try and track it working.

Comment: Are you sure the child says `.click(do_stuff)` and not `.click(do_stuff())`? The extra parentheses would cause this problem.

Comment: Is postMessage() being called anywhere else on the parent page, or any other iframes on the page?

Comment: @BenjaminRay added an alert on the child iframe and the parent page and the alert that I added on the parent page fired on page load and not the alert on the child iframe's page.  So it's definitely happening when the main page loads.

Comment: @Barmar yes, it's just like you see it in the child

Comment: Is it getting the message `child frame` or some other message?

Comment: @Barmar Everything functions correctly, but I don't want it to fire on page load.  I only want it to fire when you click from a link in the child iframe.  Would it help to see the site?

Comment: Is that an answer to my question? I'm trying to figure out whether it's the sender or the listener that's running prematurely.

Comment: Add a `debugger;` breakpoint to `do_stuff` to catch it when it runs.

Comment: @Barmar It's the listener that's running prematurely.

Comment: What's in `event.data` when this happens?

Comment: @Barmar Hello from {"widgetId":"widget_1429412705363","method":"ready","value":null}

Comment: I suspect a browser extension is sending that. Try disabling extensions and see if it goes away.

Comment: Disabled extension, same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  I took the eventlistener out of the document load on the parent frame and then used a different jquery function to call the function from the main page.

Parent page script

```
<script>
function open_post() {
        $("body").css('overflow','hidden');
        $(".overlay").show("fast");
        console.log("Hello from " + e.data);
}
</script>
```

Child iframe script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".standard").click(parent.open_post);
});
</script>
```

Worked like a charm and did not fire on parent page load.